# Getting inappropriate output in terminal

Tags: vim, c

I have written a C program in Vim and trying to open the file by command vim filename.c I am getting this output.

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name ".linklist.c.swp"
          owned by: atharva   dated: Wed Jul 17 22:29:18 2019
         file name: ~atharva/linklist.c
          modified: YES
         user name: atharva   host name: atharva-HP-Notebook
        process ID: 8235
While opening file "linklist.c"
             dated: Wed Jul 17 22:56:38 2019
      NEWER than swap file!

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the case,
    be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
    file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution.
(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r linklist.c"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file ".linklist.c.swp"
    to avoid this message.

Swap file ".linklist.c.swp" already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
```

Comment: Could you please formulate this as a question?  What are you trying to get the system to do or not do? What steps have you taken so far to accomplish that?

Comment: I am trying to open my file.c file in VIM using command vim file.c, but when i have run command (vim file.c) i am getting some unknown output.....

Comment: @Penguino I am trying to open my linklist.c file in VIM using command vim file.c, but when i have run command (vim linklist.c) i am getting some unknown output.....I want to know why it saying like (Swap file ".linklist.c.swp" already exists! [O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort: ) And what is linklist.c.swap file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computer is asking you to choose what to do by pressing a key appropriate for what you're trying to do `O,E,R,D,Q,A` for the corresponding choice that fits your situation.

The issue here is that when you open your file with two different programs the computer essentially creates two separate working copies of the file in a (swap file)--and it needs to know what to do about the copies, and which one it will store as the permanent copy to the hard-disk when you're done.

The *.swap file is the temporary copy where the file lives. You're going to need to choose what to do based on what is appropriate in your situation.